# Debug iPad app with SSL in VS through Fiddler/IIS Express - Breakpoints not being hit

Tags: ios, iis, ssl, visual-studio-2013, fiddler

I have an **iOS** device connected to my computer via proxy with **Fiddler** set to allow remote computers to connect.

Fiddler Hosts is set up to **remap the original target host to my localhost** on ssl:
127.0.0.1:443

As per [Hansellman's article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx) I've opened the correct port and have configured the bindings for ssl.

**I can see from Fiddler that my code is being hit and is responding as expected** however, I have been **unable to get the breakpoints to hit so that I can step through** (which is what I'm trying to achieve).  I have checked that the debugger is attached to IIS Express, and it all looks fine.

I believe this is something to do with IISExpress/VS as **when the site was set completely in IIS (not express) the breakpoints were hit** which leads me to suspect it's something to do with the extra legwork to make IISExpress work with ssl on port 443.

Is there some way to get the debugger to work with this?

Thankyou in advance!